# Errors in Reverting to Previous version at PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

I accidentally uploaded a newer version of my app at Google Play Store. And now i want to revert my application, I unpublished the previous version of my application and now m trying to activate the previous one but m getting the following errors:

**This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):

    It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 9 to version 8, which would occur when

    API levels in range 15+ and

    Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and

    Features containing all of [android.hardware.CAMERA, android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].**

Can anybody guide me how can i get rid of these errors. It Emergency...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you hit publish (whether staged rollout or not), you cannot downgrade to a prior version - only upgrades (i.e., from lower version code to higher version code) are allowed.

You can publish the old version of your application with an updated version code that is higher than the build you accidentally pushed - that will replace everyone's version with the old version.

Comment: Thnx, I did the same.

Comment: Thank you very much @ballake you saved my app today.. Thank you very much