# Forbidden to downgrade version error while attempting to upgrade Google Play Store

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to publish an update to my app in the google play store but i keep getting the following error

```
This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 10200 to version 15, which would occur when 
API levels in range 14+ and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.location.NETWORK, android.hardware.MICROPHONE, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
```

I'm using phonegap build to compile the app and my config.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.drop.drop"
    version   = "10400">
<name>DROP DROP</name>

<description>
    Water Saving Starts at Home.
</description>

<author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    iCOMMS Research Team
</author>

<!--
    If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
    following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
    permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->
<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
<!--
    Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
    <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
-->

<!-- Plugins -->

<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />

<!-- Third party plugins -->
<!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
<!--
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
-->

<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
<string>100</string>
</gap:config-file>

<!--
    Define access to external domains.
    <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
    <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.
    Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
-->

<access origin="*"/>
<!-- Added the following intents to support the removal of whitelist code from base cordova to a plugin -->
<!-- Whitelist configuration. Refer to https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

how to I get around this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors in Reverting to Previous version at PlayStore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787578/errors-in-reverting-to-previous-version-at-playstore)

Comment: i'm not trying to downgrade the app, i'm upgrading the app

Comment: Perhaps you wrote a wrong version number on your config files?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i've tried changing the version code to something more appropriate such as 1.2.0 as the published version is 0.0.1 which should evade this error as far as i can see. but that does not seem to be the case. i had uploaded another apk previously which was inadvertently versioned 10200 that is why the version in my config.xml matches 10400 in an attempt to rectify this